# Loaded a Matrix from a text file, throwing error loading data

Tags: matlab, matrix, probability

Working on an assignment in MatLab, I am supposed to create a 100x100 matrix that contains random numbers from 10 to 20 and store them in data.txt. Then, I am suppose to choose 3 numbers and determine the probability of finding those three numbers in `data.txt`.

It keeps throwing this error:

```
Undefined function 'printf' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Error in Lab2 (line 72)
printf('Probability of choosing %d is %.4f',num1, p1/10000);
```

Here is my code, I have a feeling I didn't create the `data.txt` file correctly or I didn't load it correctly.

```
r = round(10 + (20-10).*rand(100,100)); %(min + (max-min).*rand(xDim,yDim)

fp = fopen('data.txt','w');

fprintf(fp, '%d ',r);
fclose(fp);

filename = 'data.txt';
B = importdata(filename);

p1 = 0; p2 = 0; p3 = 0; %Counts how many times num1/2/3 shows up
num1 = 12; num2 = 19; num3 = 18; %Choice of numbers

[row col] = size(B);
for i = 1:row
    for j = 1:col
        if B(i,j) == num1
            p1 = p1 + 1;
        end
        if B(i,j) == num2
            p2 = p2 + 1;
        end
        if B(i,j) == num3
            p3 = p3+1;
        end
    end
end

printf('Probability of choosing %d is %.4f',num1, p1/10000);
printf('Probability of choosing %d is %.4f',num2, p2/10000);
printf('Probability of choosing %d is %.4f',num3, p3/10000);
```

Any help would be great! thanks!

Comment: What type of variable is `B`, i.e. in the workspace, what does it have for `B`?

Comment: @David I actually changed it up, I got the reading to work and past the if statements, but now I'm stuck on the new error. I updated the error as well.

Comment: `printf` is not a Matlab function. That's why the error says "`Undefined function printf`"

Comment: @David Oh jeez... I don't know why I didn't think of that. it's supposed to be fprintf

Comment: Also `randi(11,100,100)+9` would be a nicer way of constructing your random numbers.